# Smoothwall is blocking the registration for my vpn

Tags: vpn

I don't have WiFi at my house, so I told my foster mom I would get a VPN app on my tablet. I'm on a kindle fire, and the app I picked is called VPN by private internet access. I have to use my high school's wifi, and I figured out that smoothwall blocked the registration link. My foster family and I really need internet, but we can't afford a carrier or a plan with a mobile hotspot. I would really appreciate it if you guys would consider this request to unblock the registration link. The link is https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/buy-vpn/

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange.  You can take to the tour of how Stack Exchange works by clicking here   http://security.stackexchange.com/tour  Thanks for you contribution and again, welcome.  Cheers.

Comment: Are you asking about registering on StackExchange? It appears that you have already been successful.

Comment: Nate - I'm not sure why you thought this was the right website, but it isn't. I'm not sure I know of a better website to send you to. Perhaps PIA's support pages? You can go to a Starbuck's or something to get free internet to contact PIA and register. That said, if the firewall blocks access to PIA's registration pages, it may restrict actual use of the VPN as well. So you may be out of luck. Good luck!